# pandas iterrows() comparison only writing last result to all rows

Tags: python, pandas, loops, numpy, if-statement

The following code is **supposed** to iterate over a dataframe & write to the 'Valid' column. It is only writing the last value to all rows in 'Valid'.

```
for index, row in lxrx.iterrows():
time_cur = (row['time'])
low_val = csvm.loc['LXRX', time_cur].low
price = (row['Price'])
if price > low_val:
    lxrx['Valid'] = price
else:
    lxrx['Valid'] = 'Invalid'
```

To test I used: print(price) & print(low_val)

it output what I expect - each price then each low_val:

```
3.13  2.8    2.1  3.06    3.36  3.06
```

It Outputs the below left, instead of the below right as I wanted.

```
Index Valid     rather than     Index Valid
0     3.36                      0     3.13
1     3.36                      1     2.10
2     3.36                      2     3.36
```

I even tried nesting another for loop inside that one so that I could refer to each row in Valid but that did the same thing. How can I get it to correctly write each value?

Comment: I would suggest figuring out how to use `merge` along with vectorized operations to achieve your desired result. Not only will you be less likely to run into these sorts of issues, your code will also almost certainly run faster.

Comment: @PMende does this work for comparing indexes of different length but keeping all rows in longer series' rather than the shorter series removing duplicates?

Comment: Could you include some example data from both lxrx and csvm? Once we have that i’ll be able to write an easy, idiomatic and efficient solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is in these lines:

```
if price > low_val:
    lxrx['Valid'] = price
else:
    lxrx['Valid'] = 'Invalid'
```

This syntax applies the `price` value or 'Invalid' to the whole column.

Instead use `.loc` to specifically index the row/column where you want to enter the value:

```
if price > low_val:
    lxrx.loc[index, 'Valid'] = price
else:
    lxrx.loc[index, 'Valid'] = 'Invalid'
```

Also as has been mentioned this loop will be a slow solution to what you are trying to do, there is probably a simpler vectorized way of solving the problem, by merging the low values from `csvm` into `lxrx` as a column, and then doing something like:

`lxrx["Valid"] = np.where(lxrx["Price"] > lxrx["low_value_from_csvm"], lxrx["Price"], "Invalid")`